# Android studio XML centercrop doesn't center the image

Tags: java, android, xml, android-imageview

[image: bouclier.jpg]

I have added a `background-image` in Android Studio, I used `center-crop` to center it.

The problem I have is that the image does not center properly. it's slightly off to the right and I want it perfectly centered

Look on the right the stars are not well centered.

Here's what I have tried

[image: Layout]

Could you help me ?

Thank you.

Comment: Would it be possible to see the source image file you're using for the ImageView? (bouclier.jpg)

Comment: Post your image which you are using in background.

Comment: @TomLarcher Done I added the image.

Comment: @PratikButani Hi I added the Image you should be able to see it :)

Comment: @MohamedNecib please remove this image (which is very small) and paste the code formatted as text. If you have questions, look at [formatting help on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for updating your question with the background image (bouclier.jpg) that you're using. The issue you're experiencing is not to do with your layout (XML) code, but rather with the image itself.

[image: Your background image is offset to the right ever so slightly]

As you can see, your background image appears to be offset to the right ever so slightly (I've added a green cross in the above image to illustrate this). As a result, when you use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` the image is correctly centred but doesn't look right.

My recommendation would be to choose a different (properly centred) image to use as your background, or alternatively to centre the image you're presently using.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Not a problem at all Mohamed! Do you mind accepting my answer if it has solved your issue? Much appreciated